# Can't save id to a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm having trouble assigning an `id` field to a variable.

Given this:

```
var temp;

if(!data.obj.id){
    console.log('*************** assigning ' + data.obj.id + ' to temp');
    temp = data.obj.id;
    console.log('temp is',temp);
}else if(!data.obj._id){
    console.log('*************** assigning ' + data.obj._id + ' to temp');
    temp = data.obj._id;
    console.log('temp is: ',temp);
}

console.log('**************',data.obj._id);
console.log('**************',temp);
```

Neither of those if statements are ever true, and the console logs return,

`************  538cdd6fca343660389d4d69`

`************ undefined`

### EDIT:

I've also tried:

```
if(data.obj.hasOwnProperty('id')){
        console.log('*************** assigning ' + data.obj.id + ' to temp');
        temp = data.obj.id;
        console.log('temp is',temp);
    }else if(data.obj.hasOwnProperty('_id')){
        console.log('*************** assigning ' + data.obj._id + ' to temp');
        temp = data.obj._id;
        console.log('temp is: ',temp);
    }

    console.log('**************',data.obj._id);
    console.log('**************',temp);
```

And `temp` is still undefined.

### EDIT2:

I've changed my code to this:

```
var temp;

if(data.obj.hasOwnProperty('id')){
    console.log('*************** assigning ' + data.obj.id + ' to temp');
    temp = data.obj.id;
    console.log('temp is' + temp);
}

if(data.obj.hasOwnProperty('_id')){
    console.log('*************** assigning ' + data.obj._id + ' to temp');
    temp = data.obj._id;
    console.log('temp is' + temp);
}

console.log('**************',data.obj._id);
console.log('**************',data.obj.id);
console.log('**************',temp);
```

And I get:

```
************** 538ce08c6ced88c020ecbd07
************** 538ce08c6ced88c020ecbd07
************** undefined
```

Comment: sometimes you are using `obj._id` and some others `obj.id)`

Comment: `!data.obj.id` this will be always true, because mongodb reference is _id and not id

Comment: @juvian I'm aware. Sometimes the object has `_id`, and sometimes it has `id`. I need cases for both.

Comment: @fmodos so why is temp undefined?

Comment: If that is your output, your documents clearly have a `_id` AND a `id` field.

Comment: because temp is `temp = data.obj.id;` and `data.obj.id` is null, change the if to `if(data.obj.id){` and this should work, also do the same for the second if... get rid of the `!` in both if @Houseman

Comment: @fmodos I edited my code to account for this, and I still get the same output

Comment: @Houseman your object property might as an array try, that is why the `hasOwnProperty` is not working, just use `if(data.obj.id){`

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` will return `false` when `data.obj` is not a literal object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't log the value of `data.obj.id`, but presumably it is also true, like `_id` (in the sense that their negation returns false). Therefore, neither the first nor the second if clause are fulfilled in your example, and none of the two branches execute. It seems like you want to remove the negation operators, `!`, from both your if clauses, but it's hard to tell without context.

Comment: You were right, that both statements were true. However, I updated my code (and my question)  to account for this, and `temp` is still `undefined`. Neither of the if-statements are ever true.

Comment: @Houseman: Get rid of the `HasOwnProperty` method and use the `in` operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in